# How can I access a parent method from child component in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to call a parent/root level method on a child component in Vue.js, but I keep getting a message saying `TypeError: this.addStatusClass is not a function`.

```
Vue.component('spmodal', {
    props: ['addStatusClass'],
    created: function() {
        this.getEnvironments();
    },
    methods: {
        getEnvironments: function() {
            this.addStatusClass('test');
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
        addStatusClass(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a full JSBIN example: http://jsbin.com/tomorozonu/edit?js,console,output

If I call `this.$parent.addStatusClass('test');` it works fine, but based on the Vue.js documentation, this is bad practice and I should be using props which is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

specifying the prop does nothing on its own, you have to actually pass something to it from the parent - in this case, the function.

```
<spmodal :add-status-class="addStatusClass"></spmodal>
```